# What is the default location of the heap dump in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I had ES running in a 3Node cluster . Recently i had seen the OutofMemory exceptions in my logs . My ES has `XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` enabled which will create a heap dump when OutofMemoryError occurs. Even i checked with `ps -ef | grep elastic` command i got response like this

```
elastic+ 2527 1 11 08:47 ? 00:03:59 /usr/bin/java -Xms1720m -Xmx1720m -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Dmapper.allow_dots_in_name=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid --default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch --default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch --default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
```

My error is like this

```
[2017-06-27 06:29:36,325][DEBUG][action.search            ] [data] [content-2017][3], node[GDyfoO1ySQ-FgKGFmuJxJg], [P], v[61], s[STARTED], a[id=PN-9iOlNTICPLABsgyd3Qw]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@3fbfc52e] lastShard [true]
RemoteTransportException[[data][10.0.x.x:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: QueryPhaseExecutionException[Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space];
Caused by: QueryPhaseExecutionException[Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space];
        at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:409)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:113)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:372)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:385)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:368)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:365)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I checked all the .hprof files in my server by giving `find . -type f -name \*.hprof` this command but didnt find any files

Want to know the if heap dump will be generated for the above exception if it is where the location will be for that ?

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your command a typo 
`find . -type f -name \*.hprof` instead of `find . -type f -name \*.hrpf`

Check `pwdx <processid>` -> U will get the path where the process started from. There's a chance it gets created in that path too.

Search in all the paths like '/etc/elasticsearch', '/var/log/elasticsearch', /usr/share/elasticsearch.. etc (paths from your command output)

`-XX:HeapDumpPath=<Path>` should be included

Comment: Sry it's a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: Where can i find the process id for the above exception? Whether it is there in my above log?

Comment: 2527  is the process id (from the above given output)

Comment: May i know how you are saying 2527 is process id?

Comment: elastic+ **2527** 1 11 08:47 ? 00:03:59 /usr/bin/java -Xms1720m -Xmx1720m -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Dmapper.allow_dots_in_name=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start -d -p

Comment: Thanks @Sidhu When i used pwdx 2527 it is showing path `/usr/share/elasticsearch` . I went there and searched for `ls *.hprof` files but didnt find any. Is the above exception will create a heap dump?

Comment: The main problem i didn't given the path explicitly so it points to default path . Not sure what the default path is.